# How to add self signed SSL certificate to jHipster sample app?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have create sample jHipster app. Now I want to add self signed SSL certificate and test in local to have a access to https. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

These instructions are applicable for all Spring Boot applications, on which JHipster is based. I have tested this on a newly generated [JHipster 2.7](http://jhipster.github.io/2015/04/03/jhipster-release-2.7.0.html) project.

You need to complete these steps when starting from scratch:

1. Generate a self-signed certificate
2. Add the SSL properties to your application.properties or application.yml as mentioned in the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl)
3. (Optional) Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

---

### Generating a self-signed certificate

First you need to generate your self-signed certificate in your project directory, this can be done with `keytool`, which is utility script provided by Java:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650
Enter keystore password:  
Re-enter new password:
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  
Is CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown correct?
  [no]:  yes
```

I have chosen password `mypassword` so this is the one I will use in the next step. When you have done this, you will see a `keystore.p12` in your current directory.

### Add the SSL properties to your `application.properties` or `application.yml` as mentioned in the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl)

Now you need to add the HTTPS connector properties for Tomcat. You can find the property (yml) files in `src/main/resources/` and you need to update the `application.yml` (or if it is only for development in `application-dev.yml` with the following properties:

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: keystore.p12
    key-store-password: mypassword
    keyStoreType: PKCS12
    keyAlias: tomcat
```

Now you can package your application with Maven (or Gradle if you chose that for your JHipster application) using `mvn clean package` and run the application using **mvn spring-boot:run**. You can now access your application on **https://localhost:8080**

For simplicity I did not change the port, but ideally you should change it as well in the properties files, but I left it out since they are already defined in `application-dev.yml` and `application-prod.yml` so you would have to change it in there or remove it and put it in the general `application.yml`

---

### (Optional) Add redirect HTTP to HTTPS

You can only enable one protocol through the `application.properties`, so when you do this like above only HTTPS will work. If you want HTTP to work too, and redirect to HTTPS you have to add a `@Configuration` class like below

```
@Bean
  public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new      TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
          SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
          securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
          SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
          collection.addPattern("/*");
          securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
          context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
      };

    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(initiateHttpConnector());
    return tomcat;
  }

  private Connector initiateHttpConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setRedirectPort(8443);

    return connector;
  }
```

This response is basically a copy of my blog post on the same subject: http://www.drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/

Comment: do i need to keep  keystore.p12 file in project's classpath?

Comment: I left the keystore.p12 in the root of my project and ran from the root with mvn spring-boot:run. If you put it on your classpath you can change the key-store property to: key-store: classpath:keystore.p12

Comment: Hi @Driss. now i'm not able to access sample app .. if I type http://127.0.0.1:8080/# in the browser, i.e., if I type http:// it should redirect me to https://

Comment: You can only activate one protocol through the application properties at this time. If you want HTTP and HTTPS you will need to active one programmatically. I blogged about this use case on http://www.drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/ and I'll edit the response here too

Comment: thank you ..  It means I can create ContainerConfiguration.java in config package of jHipster sample app and paste code snippet mentioned in blog?

Comment: Yes, just make sure you annotate it with @Configuration

Comment: thanks I am able to run my app with https from eclipse, but if I run if from jar package it throws me a port error, do I need to configure anything else?

Comment: @DrissAmn Your sample shows keyStoreType and keyAlias as two of the property names.  Is it supposed to be key-store-type and key-alias?  That's what IntelliJ's intellisense shows and it's odd to see "dash" based property names mixed with  "camel" cased property names.

Comment: Spring Boot uses relaxed binding so both ways work. But it would make more sense to pick one way and stick consistently with it in a real project.

Comment: Can someone please add imports for redirect HTTP to HTTPS code ?

Comment: I did every step beside last one since you didnt put imports and it doesn't work : http://prntscr.com/kfb2ni

Comment: I konow this may be too late, but i have followed all steps and I get: Your connection is not private. Btw  I am running the server in dev profile.

Answer (score 5):

To extend the [Driss Amri brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522114/how-to-add-self-signed-ssl-certificate-to-jhipster-sample-app/29582178#29582178) on how to re-enable `BrowserSync`.

If you choose not to support http, or if http is redirected to https, `BrowserSync` will not work. To make it work again, few changes are necessary in:

1. **gulp/config.js**, `apiPort` and `uri` to:

   ```
   apiPort: 8443, 
   uri: 'https://localhost:',
   ```
2. **gulp/serve.js**: add `options.rejectUnauthorized = false;` into `proxyRoutes` so that node does not complain about self signed certificate:

   ```
   proxyRoutes.map(function (r) {
       var options = url.parse(baseUri + r);
       options.route = r;
       options.preserveHost = true;
       options.rejectUnauthorized = false;
       return proxy(options);
   }));
   ```
3. optionally let `BrowserSync` serve content over https too. I recommend it with `Spring Social` to save some trouble. Just add `https: true` into `browserSync` call in gulp/serve.js:

   ```
   browserSync({
       open: true,
       port: config.port,
       server: {
           baseDir: config.app,
           middleware: proxies
       },
       https: true
   });
   ```

   Now BrowserSync will serve content with self signed certificate shipped with it. It is possible to reuse the one created for `Spring Boot`, more on [BrowserSync homepage](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-https).

Answer (score 2):

For those using webpack instead of gulp you can complete [Driss Amri's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522114/how-to-add-self-signed-ssl-certificate-to-jhipster-sample-app/29582178#29582178) answer with two changes:

modify the **proxy.conf.json**:

```
{
    "*": {
        "target": "https://localhost:8443",
        "secure": true
    }
}
```

this will redirect API requests to the new https address.
Then alter also webpack file for instance here a **webpack.dev.js** modified example:

```
module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
devtool: 'eval-source-map',
devServer: {
    contentBase: './target/www',
    proxy: [{
        context: [
            /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
            '/api',
            '/management', ...
            '/auth'
        ],
        target: 'https://127.0.0.1:8443',
        /* set secure to false here, otherwise self-signed certification cause DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT proxy errors */
        secure: false
    }]
},
```

Comment: What about prod ? webpackprod.prod.js ? Since Driss Amri's answer is not working for me what can i change there ?

Comment: Webpack make uses of environment variables as explained here: https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/managing-dev-and-production-builds-webpack so for instance the name would be webpack.prod.js within this case