# Java Spring stand alone Rest server - how to implement SSL\HTTPS?

Tags: java, spring, rest, ssl, https

I've implemented a basic Rest servlet - that accepts HTTP requests - quite easily.
Now I have to configure it to work with SSL (i.e. validate certificate upon request)
This is the skeleton of the code I have so far:

```
   @RestController
public class MgmtController  {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mgmt", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void post(@RequestBody CustomImpl request, HttpServletRequest httpRequest, response httpResponse) {    

        System.out.println(request);    
    }
```

can it even be done programmatically?

thanks

Comment: Certificate is negotiated on server, not app code.

Comment: well, the server code does that... is it too complicated to create manually?

Comment: what webserver are you using?

Comment: no web server - it's a standalone java code based on Spring security.

Comment: Found the answer, this can be done:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522114/how-to-add-self-signed-ssl-certificate-to-jhipster-sample-app/29582178#29582178

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat server, you can find all about SSL configuration [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)