# Spring Boot - enable and configure SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, https

I have this certificates / files in order to enable SSL for my application:

[image: certificates]

I found out that this properties are needed for Spring Boot to enable HTTPS:

```
server.port=8089
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=****
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
```

but this does not work. My question now would be what do I have to do in order to get it work? https://abc.lehr.co.at should be the URL.

**[EDIT]**

I have created my own keystore - with this I get the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Alias name tomcat does not identify a key entry
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:596)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:534)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:363)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:739)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:472)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol.start(Http11NioProtocol.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986)
```

My keystore looks like this:

[image: Keystore]

Actually I don't know what to import into keystore for embedded tomcat (Spring Boot).

Comment: `server.ssl.enabled=true` would be a good start.

Comment: There are tons of example available [online](https://www.google.fr/search?q=spring+boot+ssl+configuration). Give it a try first, and if you are stuck, give us the detail of what you tried and what failed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522114/how-to-add-self-signed-ssl-certificate-to-jhipster-sample-app/29582178#29582178

Comment: Does anyone know how to achieve above pro grammatically in spring boot. We've to read keystore file path and password at run time from a remote location and fill in this assuming SSL object and would like spring to inject that as part of it's initialization. Anyidea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To enable SSL, you must provide a private key, and not a trusted certificate.

In your keystore, 'tomcat' should be listed as an alias for a **privatekeyentry** and not a **trustedcertentry**.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pack your private keys to PFX file or P12 with specifiyng aliases. So, it will be picked up accordingly from the keyStore after loading materials.

Use this tool to figure out what alias are:

```
keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore my_debug_keystore.p12 -storepass debug
```

Answer (score 2):

```
server.port=8089
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=****
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat << This should be the alias of yourfile.12 if you have forgotten just create a new one and replace it>>
```

And dnt forget to add

```
security.require-ssl=true <<Tell Spring Security (if used) to require requests over HTTPS>>
```

Comment: security.require-ssl=true is depricated in Spring Boot 2

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you create your KeyStore in JKS format:

```
 keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias my_alias -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

then add the configuration:

```
server.port=8089
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=****
server.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS
server.ssl.keyAlias=my_alias
```

Comment: The format doesn't matter; Java and Spring have handled all formats for a long time, as long as you specify correctly. Also since 9 (since Dec. 2018) keytool no longer defaults to JKS anyway. **Using `-genkey` _does_ help _if_ your clients will accept a selfsigned cert**, which not all will.

Answer (score 0):

First you may convert your .pem file to a DER and then generate a keystore.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13992135/16358980 how to do this.

In your application.properties, change key-store property to your generated keystore file:

```
server.ssl.key-store=<your-generated-keystore>
```