# Enable SSL (HTTPS) in spring rest Api

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, ssl

Hi I want to enable ssl in my spring rest application. That should be accessible by providing certificate only. How can I achieve this. It's new topic for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot - enable and configure SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534219/spring-boot-enable-and-configure-ssl-certificate)

Comment: See [X.509 Authentication in Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security). Your question is too broad for SO unfortunately. Try it first, and if it doesn't work, post your issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get a certificate or create one.
2. Enable it:

   server.ssl.key-store: keystore.p12

   server.ssl.key-store-password: mypassword

   server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12

   server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat

Comment: Is there any requirement that only private entry should be there in certificate and my keystore type is jks