# Adding SSL to sprint boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, https, openssl

I bought ssl from godaddy. In the zip downloaded I got three files.

```
xxxxx.crt xxxxx.pem gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

How can I use these files to secure by spring boot service?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534219/spring-boot-enable-and-configure-ssl-certificate

Comment: https://medium.com/jinternals/enable-https-with-godaddy-ssl-using-spring-boot-bdb7371ca26c

Comment: I installed ngnix on my server. setting up nginix will godaddy ssl files is easy and may blogs were there. then I proxied every SSL request to my spring boot.