# Jhipster, your connection is not private

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, jhipster

I am trying to use `SSL certificate` to access my `jhipster` app with `https`.
I have followed the instructions on: [How to add self signed SSL certificate to jHipster sample app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522114/how-to-add-self-signed-ssl-certificate-to-jhipster-sample-app)
, but when i try to access the page I get the message that `your connection is not private`. When i continue to the page i can see on the left side from URL:`not secured`, when i click on it it says that my certificate is not active, however it also tells that it's valid for next 10 years.
Have anyone faced the same issue?
Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

All about my project:

```
"jhipsterVersion": "4.14.1",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "jwt",
"cacheProvider": "ehcache",
"enableHibernateCache": true,
"websocket": false,
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
"prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
"searchEngine": false,
"messageBroker": false,
"serviceDiscoveryType": false,
"buildTool": "maven",
"enableSocialSignIn": true,
"enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
"jwtSecretKey": "",
"clientFramework": "angularX",
"useSass": false,
"clientPackageManager": "yarn",
"applicationType": "monolith",
"jhiPrefix": "jhi",
"enableTranslation": false
```

Comment: https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2017/01/28/ssl-configuration-on-spring-boot-application-with-self-signed-certificate/ found this article. I will report if i will find something useful.

Comment: As I understand, i Have to activate my certificate, any tips on how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2017/01/28/ssl-configuration-on-spring-boot-application-with-self-signed-certificate/

from the link above:

if the site is public facing it would be better to go for the public CA signed certificate rather the self signed. So if you have public CA signed certificate then client browser do verify the certificate without any problem because the browser by default identifies the public CAs otherwise it will show as follows which is not trusted site `unless you import the certificate to the browser trust store.`

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSJJ9R_6.0.2/com.ibm.team.jp.jrs.doc/topics/t_jrs_brwsr_cert_cfg.html#chrome

- website that guides you through importing/installign self signed certificate.